# Access jquery variables within ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I have values stored in an array using jquery. How can I access these array elements using asp.net?

Comment: You're missing some detail from your question.  jQuery works on the client side (in the memory space of the user's browser).  C# works on the server side (in the memory space of the server).  Typically, HTTP is used to communicate plain text with different formats between these two worlds.  I will call this the "client/server" model.  Could you please explain, in a *lot* more detail, what you mean by your question?

Comment: I am storing my items of a select list in an array using a jquery function. Now on button click I want to access these array values in a method.

Comment: You can pass them via HTTP Request to a C# ASHX handler perhaps. For example, if you use C# Web Service to read values into a form and want to submit them back to the server. However, I would not advise to pass JavaScript to C# via the client-side. Doesn't seem like a good pratice.

Comment: Thanks guys! All help appreciated.

Comment: update post with the code used to store array from select and more detail about objective

Comment: I'd suggest sending them via AJAX as a JSON string which can be parsed serverside.

Answer (score 0):

If this is on an ASP.NET web form (aspx page) then you can just write the contents of the array into a hidden text field and click the button to submit the form. Then your code-behind will have access to that data.